# Second (independent) while loop not executing in Perl

Tags: perl, oop, while-loop, io

I am trying to read two separate files using two independent while loops using a Perl script. I am using the object oriented way to read files (Module IO::File). The first while loop to read file1 is working perfectly but the second while loop to read file2 is not reading anything. My code is as follows,

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use 5.18.0;
 use warnings;
 use IO::File;
 $file1="file1.dat";
 $file2="file2.dat";
 my $f1 = IO::File -> new("< $file1") or die "Cannot read file1: $!"; 
 my $f2 = IO::File -> new("< $file2") or die "Cannot read file2: $!";

 while ( $linef1 = $f1 -> getline() ){
      data extraction from file 1 
}
$f1 -> close;
while ( $linef2 = $f2 -> getline() ){
    data extraction from file 2
   }
```

I wrote several print statements inside the second while loop to see if they are executing or not. I found that the print statements were not executing which means the program is not entering the second while loop. It means that there is probably something wrong with the getline() statement of the second while loop but I don't know how to fix that. Any help would be appreciated.
Edit:I have omitted some variable declarations in the code for brevity.

Edit2: Here is a minimal example of what I am doing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.18.0;
use warnings;
use IO::File;

my $output_filename = $ARGV[0];
my $file = substr($output_filename,0,-4);
my $line;
my $linef;
my $foo = 0;
my $bar = 0;
my $fchk_filename = "hcho_fr.fchk";

my $fout = IO::File -> new("< $output_filename") or die "Cannot read log file: $!"; 
my $ffchk = IO::File -> new("< $fchk_filename") or die "Cannot read fchk file: $!";

 while ( $line = $fout -> getline() ){
    if ($line =~ /Initial\sParameters/){
      $foo++;
      print("Still in the first while loop.\n");
     }
  }

  print("First while loop completed.\n");
  $fout -> close;

  while ( $linef = $ffchk -> getline() ){
  print("Entered the second while loop.\n");
  if ( $linef =~ /Cartesian Gradient/ ){
    $bar++;
    print("Still in the second while loop.\n");
     }
   }

   print("Successfully executed.\n");
```

This code ran without any errors and gave me the following output.

```
   Still in the first while loop.
   Still in the first while loop.
   First while loop completed.
   Successfully executed.
```

Comment: It's working fine on my machine ( Ubuntu 16.04, Perl 5.22 ). Though some `my` keywords had to be added first to silence warnings.

Comment: I don't see any errors -- and I tested and it works fine (v5.10).  Does your first loop complete --  did you try to print between the loops? Are the files cetainly OK? Can you show a full example, together with some short sample files?

Comment: For one thing, your "_data extraction ..._" may be getting you in an infinite loop in either `while`, or exiting the second loop right away.

Comment: Oh. I am running it on openSUSE 13.1, Perl 15.8. I am not printing anything between the loops. When I am running the loops from two different perl scripts, it is working fine but not when I am running them from the same script. Also, I am not getting any error while compiling the code.

Comment: @zdim If I am entering an infinite loop in either of the while loops, then the print statements outside of the loops should not work, right?

Comment: OK. Nothing's wrong with what you do show that I can tell.  Either show a mininmal _full_ example with a  problem, or debug -- say, enter a print statement between loops and one right at the start of the second `while`, _before any processing_. Also add a print after the second `while`.

Comment: Of course, in an infinite loop your program would appear to hang.  i mentioned that because it wasn't completely clear to me from the question whether it may be the case.  If your program does complete (exit) then you don't have that.

Comment: @zdim I have tried all the possible combination of print statements outside of the loop. They are working. But any print statement or anything is not working inside the second while loop.

Comment: Since print statements are working outside of the loops, I thought the while condition of the second while loop is false somehow, but I can't figure out the error in the getline statement. I don't know if the error is due to an older version of perl.

Comment: Then all I could suggest is to show a full example of the problem, of course distilled to a minimal case, to make sense to dump here. (In the process you may well find the error.)

Comment: @tobiuchiha Like I said in my first comment, it works for me on v5.10, a _much_ older version.  It looks very much like that there is a processing glitch (possible to show up when you merged scripts) or something with a file. It could be as simple as a typo.

Comment: Are you sure your 2nd file, `hcho_fr.fchk` has a non-zero size?

Comment: @zdim OK. Since this kind of code is working for you guys, I guess I will try to run it on a different machine. I have posted a minimal example above. You can try running it. But it is not running correctly on my machine. I will update the post when I find a solution. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: @PerlDog Oh. f**k. You are right. That file is supposed generate automatically from some other program. I didn't see that. The file is there. I never felt so stupid before.

Comment: @tobiuchiha Not stupid -- you got to it with your debugging, the rest  is a matter of a bit of experience, to conclude that something's the matter with the file (emtpy in this case) in spite of what we expect that it "should" be.

Comment: @tobiuchiha One thing to suggest -- consider carefully the comments people post.  This was in my very first comment above "_Are the files cetainly OK?_"  (I _do not_ mean to blame you for it with this comment! :)

Comment: @zdim Yes. You are right. I checked the file before I started writing the program. But while writing, I mistakenly took 'write' for fchk rather than 'read' and then didn't realize that Perl changed my fchk file. I will never forget your suggestion and advice. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: @tobiuchiha  Yep, this is precisely (one of the ways) how we learn and get better -- when such convoluted developments hit us. But please accept that I _did not_ mean to criticize you in any way! As for "_consider carefully_" -- it happens to me all the time, to fail to fully appreciate things plainly stated in comments.

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few thoughts:

Most likely - does the second file begin with a blank line? Is it possible that you're getting an empty but true value? Perhaps better to check

```
while ( defined($linef = $ffchk -> getline()) ){
  print("Entered the second while loop.\n");
  if ( $linef =~ /Cartesian Gradient/ ){
    $bar++;
    print("Still in the second while loop.\n");
  }
}
```

Just to make sure you're getting a defined value back versus a possibly empty value.

What happens if you read a different file? or the same file as the first loop? make sure it's not something simple, like a lack of a newline.

Finally, have you tried adding "$| = 1" to your code to make sure the output isn't being buffered somewhere? It's a long shot, but sometimes output can appear like it's not being displayed because it's sitting in a buffer waiting to be flushed before it shows up. I doubt that's happening here, but it's a good way to make absolutely sure.

These are just some random thoughts based on what you describe.

Comment: A blank line (`"\n"`) is true. The only time that `defined` will help if the entire file consists of single byte `0` (not followed by a newline).

Comment: They are reading from a file, not a pipe, so there's no program in which to place `$| = 1;`.